how to access getIt (service locator) inside firebase messaging background handler
I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging with a background message handler, annotated with @pragma('vm:entry-point'), in my Flutter app. Inside the background handler, I call getIt as my service locator to obtain an AudioPlayer instance. However, I encounter the following error:
An error occurred in your background messaging handler:
Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type AudioPlayer is not registered inside GetIt.
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
I have registered AudioPlayer with GetIt and injectable, and it works fine in the foreground state handler for Firebase setup. My dependency injection is set up as follows:
Injection file:
final getIt = GetIt.instance;

@InjectableInit()
Future<void> configureDependencies() => getIt.init();

Dependency Module:
@module
abstract class CoreModule {
  @lazySingleton
  AudioPlayer get audioPlayer => AudioPlayer();
  // Other dependencies...
}

Firebase Messaging Setup:
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
Background Handler:
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage notificationResponse) async {
  final audioPlayer = getIt<AudioPlayer>();
  // Additional code...
}

this may help background handler
